# Can I use an asterisk to match any character in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to be able to download files by sending an sms to my router (installed openwrt) with the keyword **download http://sites.com/file.exe** can I do this?

```
if [ "$MESSAGE" = "download http*" ]; then
    aria2c httpxxxx 
fi
```

I also want to be able to pass that download link on my sms to aria2c, how can I do that? I'm using this [sms gateway](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com) on my router I'm sorry I'm not a computer guy so I don't know much about stuff like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish it simply with [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) with the [`[[ ]]`Conditional Construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)'s `==` operator:

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching

Code:

```
if [[ "$MESSAGE" == "download http"* ]]; then
    aria2c ${MESSAGE/*http/http}
fi
```

In this way you're matching messages starting with `download http` and followed by any string (null included)

---

If you want a case-insensitive solution (taken by your comments), you can firstly convert `$MESSAGE` to lower case:

```
MESSAGE=${MESSAGE,,} #If you need $MESSAGE untouched, just use a new var name
```

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use a `regex`. For example:

```
if [[ "$MESSAGE" =~ "download http" ]]
then
    aria2c httpxxxx 
fi
```

as suggested by @dgunchev you can use this as well, so that "ABCdownload http123" won't match

```
[[ "$MESSAGE" =~ ^"download http" ]]
```

Comment: You can even do it without the last `.*`: `[[ "$MESSAGE" =~ ^"download http" ]]`